# Passing SQLite variables in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am writing a app in python and utilzing sqlite.  I have a list of strings which I would like to add too the database, where each element represents some data which coincides with the column it will be put.

currently I have something like this

```
cursor.execute("""insert into credit
                    values ('Citi','5567','visa',6000,9.99,'23',9000)""")
```

I can add strings easily but dont know how to add the variables of my list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use parameters to `.execute()`:

```
query = """
     INSERT INTO credit
         (bank, number, card, int1, value, type, int2)
     VALUES
          (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        """
data =  ['Citi', '5567', 'visa', 6000, 9.99, '23', 9000]

cursor.execute(query, data)
```

According to [PEP249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

> ***`.execute(operation[,parameters])`***:
>
> *Prepare and execute a database operation (query or command).  Parameters may be provided as sequence or mapping and will be bound to variables in the operation. Variables are specified in a database-specific notation (see the module's **`paramstyle`** attribute for details)*

Checking `paramstyle`:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> print sqlite3.paramstyle
qmark
```

`qmark` means you use `?` for parameters.