# Passing multiple variables to the SQLite query in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite query in python code (as shown below) which uses version numbers as 'strings' and I have to pass these versions ('1.2.7' and '3.7.10' in the below query) as variables (v1,v2).

I was successful in using '?' for passing one variable (pname) for 'name' attribute. I am unsure of how to pass multiple variables in the SQLite query which appears multiple times.

```
    c.execute( """
    select name,version from packages
    where name = ? and 
    1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 
    between 
    1000000 * replace('1.2.7', '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr('1.2.7', instr('1.2.7', '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace('1.2.7', '.', '000') % 1000
    and
    1000000 * replace('3.7.10', '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr('3.7.10', instr('3.7.10', '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace('3.7.10', '.', '000') % 1000
    """ ,(pname,))
```

Something like:

```
    c.execute( """
    select name,version from packages
    where name = ? and 
    1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 
    between 
    1000000 * replace(V1, '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr(V1, instr(V1, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace(V1, '.', '000') % 1000
    and
    1000000 * replace(V2, '.', 'x') +
    1000 * replace(substr(V2, instr(V2, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
    replace(V2, '.', '000') % 1000
    """ ,(pname,))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing SQLite variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793970/passing-sqlite-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could try is by using string replacement as per the docs on sqlite3 for python

```
v1 = '1.2.7'
v2 = '3.7.10'

c.execute( """
  select name,version from packages
  where name = ? and 
  1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 
  between 
  1000000 * replace(?2, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(?2, instr(?2, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(?, '.', '000') % 1000
  and
  1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(?, '.', '000') % 1000
  """ ,(pname,v1,v2))
```

So just replace all params with `?` and pass the fill list of values in at the end as data.

Comment: I am using sqlite3 python library.

Comment: @prash Might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793970/passing-sqlite-variables-in-python, this could be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP's not asking how to bind values to parameters in a query, he's asking how to bind a single value to *multiple* uses of a parameter.

Comment: He does mention the need to pass the values '1.2.7' and '3.7.10' as v1 and v2 so I'm not sure what you mean, as that is not his need

Answer (score 0):

Use explicitly numbered parameters (`?1` to refer to the first bound value, `?2` to the second, and so on):

```
c.execute( """
  select name,version from packages
  where name = ?1 and 
  1000000 * replace(version, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(version, instr(version, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(version, '.', '000') % 1000 
  between 
  1000000 * replace(?2, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(?2, instr(?2, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(?2, '.', '000') % 1000
  and
  1000000 * replace(?3, '.', 'x') +
  1000 * replace(substr(?3, instr(?3, '.') + 1), '.', 'x') +
  replace(?3, '.', '000') % 1000
""" ,(pname,v1,v2))
```

You can also have named parameters instead of numbered, but I'm not sure how to use them on the Python end.